# Can I use multiple Content-type's on same page?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this php code that grabs binary( blob ) data from the database and displays as an image in a browser. However, everything after this is ignored. Is there a way that I can also use text `queries/forms/tables`? Basic HTML elements on the same page?

Having a page that can only display a picture from the DB and nothing else is useless to me.

```
<?php
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','draftdb');
    if (!$mysqli)
    die("Can't connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    $imageid= 1;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT PICTURE_ID FROM display WHERE INDEX_ID =?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $imageid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($image);
    $stmt->fetch();
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image; 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only have one `Content-Type` per page.

What you should do is simply create another page, that contains both an image (with src pointing to the code you showed) and the form you want to display, like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="image.php" alt="image retreived from DB" />
        </div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="foo" />
            ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a header content of an image type, the only information that can be displayed on this page is the image itself.  It is possible though to use a sub-php script inside of a large script, and have the sub-script return the image header, and then have the regular script do other things with this.

Sou you could do this: `<img src="\path\to\php\script" />` inside of your other script and it would work as you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple content-types in one http response.

To make a page with a picture from your DB you can make a regular page and use one of these options for your `img` tags:

1. `src="your_picture_script.php?pic_id=xxxx"` - 'your_picture_script.php' will be pretty much the example in your question.
2. `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64encode($image);?>"` - $image is the actual jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you displaying the image in an `<img>` tag? Then writing the other HTML elements below it?

The `Content-Type` header tells the browser which type of data it is going to display. You can display images in HTML, not HTML in images (unless it's an image of HTML code).